# How to plot spherical geodesics in the Kerr metric in maple?

Tags: general-relativity, coordinate-systems, computational-physics, software, kerr-metric

I need to plot geodesics in the Kerr Newman Nut metric, but to do that I need to understand how to build geodesics for an already known Kerr metric in maple. I understand that in order to build geodesics you need to numerically solve differential equations, but I get nonsense. These are the geodesics I need to build on the work of Edward Theo.

[image]

[image]

Here I have already substituted the values

[image]

The graph is not a sphere but incomprehensible nonsense

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: From the [Help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): “While computational physics is on topic, we are not a programming site. If your question is about implementing computational code - in particular, if it's about writing, compiling, debugging or optimizing code, or about a specific language or library - then it is off topic.“

Comment: I have no idea whether you are supposed to get “a sphere”. But how do you expect to get anything spherical if you are plotting $\theta$ and $\phi$ as if they are Cartesian coordinates? Also, plotting $s$ as the $z$ coordinate doesn’t make sense; it’s the geodesic parameter and you should be doing a parametric plot.

Comment: If you use the first order equations you can't handle the turning points, I would rather suggest to use the second order equations as they are used [here](http://kerr.newman.yukterez.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Personnaly, I have numerically integrated in Python the parametric equations of Kerr null geodesics, starting from points located  on photon "spheres" and I have found the same results as Edward Theo.

I think something is wrong in your programming.

Best regards.